# Interface method have List<Objects>, but implemented class methods are List<MyClass>, which is not allowed

Tags: java, interface, overriding

I am working on Interface which was implemented by different classes, but I am facing issues while I override the method in the classes.

Please help me defining proper method arguments in Interface which can be overridden by other class methods also

```
Interface I1
{
public doProcessing(List<Object> list);
}
```

Here are the classes

```
Class A implements I1
{

 public doProcessing(List<MyAbcclass> list)//This is not accepted 
  {
    //do processing
  }
}

Class B implements I1
{

  public doProcessing(List<MyXyzclass> list)//This is not accepted 
  {
    //do processing
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `public doProcessing(List<? extends Object> list);`

Comment: Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html and also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your wanted behavior:

```
interface I1<T> {
    void doProcessing(List<T> list);
}

class A implements I1<MyAbcclass> {


    @Override
    public void doProcessing(List<MyAbcclass> list) {

    }
}
```